# vsftpd login info issue

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-16.04, vsftpd

The server is ubuntu 16.04. I can login vsftpd as the following:

```
ftp> open MY_FTP_IP
Connected to MY_FTP_IP.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (MY_FTP_IP:ACCOUNT_NAME): someftpuser
```

The problem is that `ACCOUNT_NAME` is my sudoers's name, and I don't want the ftp user to see it. How do I change or remove that `ACCOUNT_NAME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following ftp flag:

```
ftp -n
```

> -n - Restrains ftp from attempting ''auto-login'' upon initial connection.
>
> If auto-login is enabled, ftp will check the .netrc (see
>   netrc(5)) file in the user's home directory for an entry describing an
>   account on the remote machine. If no entry exists, ftp will prompt for
>   the remote machine login name (**default is the user identity on the
>   local machine**), and, if necessary, prompt for a password and an
>   account with which to login.

More info in [ftp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp)

In your case execute to following command:

```
ftp -n MY_FTP_IP
```